# Primefaces AJAX event not working inside tabView

Tags: primefaces

How can I use an AJAX listener inside a tabview. Whenever the tab opened(or for a mouse click anywhere), the listener need to execute. I tried with event=click,change,blur etc, but not worked.

```
<p:tabView activeIndex="#{backingbean.tanIndex}">
<p:ajax  event="?"  listener="#{backingbean.setTabIndex}" />
```

in view.jsf:

```
<p:tabView>
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{employeeEdit.onTabChange}">
```

in edit.jsf:

```
 <p:tabView activeIndex="#{employeeEdit.tabIndex}">
```

in backingBean:

```
private int tabIndex;
public int onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event)
  {  
   // Here I'm getting event.getTab().getId() and set it to `tabIndex` property.
  }
```

When editing I need redirect to the that tab which is active in view. So if I didn't change the tab `onTabChange()` will not execute and `tabIndex` has its old value only.
I'm using Primefaces version-3.0.M3.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was a Primefaces bug that was fixed in the newest 3.0.1 release:
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17288

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Primefaces 5.1

As long as i put the tabview into a form everything worked fine.
But because i wanted to use seperate forms in my tabs i had to remove the surrounding form of the tabview to avoid nested forms. 
Without the surrounding form the ajax event didn´t get triggered any more when changing the tab.

My solution was to use a remotecommand in a form parallel to the tabview.
The remotecommand is triggered by the onTabChange attribute of the tabview element.
At that call i forwarded the index parameter to the global request parameters.

```
<p:tabView id="rootTabMenu" styleClass="tabcontainer" prependId="false" 
        activeIndex="#{sessionData.activeTabIndex}" widgetVar="rootTabMenu"
        onTabChange="tabChangeHelper([{name: 'activeIndex', value: index}])">
    // Tabs...  
</p:tabView>

<h:form id="tabChangeHelperForm">
    <p:remoteCommand name="tabChangeHelper" actionListener="#{sessionData.onTabChange()}" />
</h:form>
```

In the backing bean i catched the value again from the request parameter map and set the active index.

```
public void onTabChange()
{   
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> paramMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String paramIndex = paramMap.get("activeIndex");
    setActiveTabIndex(Integer.valueOf(paramIndex));
    System.out.println("Active index changed to " + activeTabIndex);
}
```

Hope that can help you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what I am writing is true for ver 3.0.M3. I have in front of the documentation of ver 3.0RC2 and there is a paragraph about this, with explaination and sample code (chapter `TabView`, paragraph `Ajax Behaviour Events`). You should have a look at that.

This is the part of the sample code that should help most:

```
<p:tabView>
    <p:ajax event=”tabChange” listener=”#{bean.onChange}” />
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: event="tabChange" is fine with  3.0.M3, but if I didn't change the tab, AJAX listener will not execute. So what I coded in backing bean doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you update your question with more information, like the backing bean and what you exactly want to do

Answer (score 0):

Jaron has an answer that the 3.0.1 release fixed this but I had this all the way up to 3.5 i believe i was still having this problem. on firefox and IE, the javascript handler for the Tabs weren't firing the ajax event. On google chrome, for whatever reason, it actually worked.

I moved up to Primefaces 5.0 today and this does NOT have the problem any longer. So at the very worst-case, go to Primefaces 5.0 and you'll be all good in the hood